# How do I setup this custom scrolling plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, scroll

I'm trying to get [this](http://idiotwu.github.io/smooth-scrollbar/) plugin working but I'm not exactly sure how it works. 
[Github](https://github.com/idiotWu/smooth-scrollbar#common-mistakes)

It comes with a lot of files, but do I need all of them? That's the part that is overwhelming me the most.

So let's say I set up a simple site as so:

```
-css
   -style.css
-js
   -main.js
-index.html
```

In a file structure like this, how would I implement this plugin? Which files are required? How do I initalize it? The docs gives me some info, but not enough for a beginner.

Any help would be so much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just try

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/smooth-scrollbar.css">
<script src="dist/smooth-scrollbar.js"></script>
```

of course the location before `dist` would be where you saved your plugin.

e.g. `smooth-scrollbar/dist/smooth-scrollbar.js`

Comment: What are all these other files then?

Comment: probably source files. If you open up `smooth-scrollbar.js` it's a minified version, which makes downloading and running it faster. This is probably also open source, which means you can play around with the other files to either update their functionalities or just look at how they programmed it.